# Change the origin of the canvas

Tags: coordinates

I'm developing a mapping software. Coordinates are plotted with respect to some point (origin) inside the canvas, not the default origin, so the canvas is divided into four quadrants. The mouse hovers over the canvas and the labels are updated to show the current mouse position inside the canvas of course with appropiate signs of the coordinates. So basically the trick is to change the origin and assign it to some point in the canvas

Can anyone please help me how to do this. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What does this have to do with WOW64? You're going to have to be a lot more specific with the tags if you want anyone to see this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the Win32 API, [SetViewportOrgEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923809.aspx) is what you're looking for.